# How can I delete all PDA accounts for my program (anchor)?

Tags: anchor, pda, delete

I created several PDA accounts with custom data fields. However, I realized that I want to add a new variable inside; since I have already made the accounts and allocated space for them, I can't just go in lib.rs and make changes (... unless I can? but I get error saying that my account failed to serialize/deserialize).

Is there a way to delete these accounts so I may make new ones with the correct space inside?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can close PDAs using anchor. Here's an example from my own code, closing my `Counts` PDA:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(countsbump: u8)]
pub struct CloseCounts<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut, seeds = [COUNTSSEED], bump = countsbump, close = user)]
    pub counts_account: AccountLoader<'info, Counts>,
    pub system_program: Program <'info, System>,
}
```

The key there is the `close = user` part. I.e. the user account will receive the rent back.

However, this is still a bit unwieldy because you have to run the `close` **before** you make changes to the struct. Then make the changes, then re-create the new PDAs.

The way I solved it is just adding versioning to my seeds. So there is "countsv1", "countsv2", ... for the seed of my Counts PDA. I put it in a constant named COUNTSSEED, so I have to increase it only in one place.

So everytime I make changes, I'll just leave the old PDAs hanging around on Devnet, and work with the new ones with the seed version. :-)

I learned to love this procedure, it's making life a lot easier for me.

Comment: Yes, just to add context the account has to be closed and it won't be properly deleted until the end of the block. This is why it's important to use the `close` keyword in anchor, because it modifies the discriminator so that no one else can reinitialize the account with another transaction in the same block. After the block finishes you can recreate the account anyway you like.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Could you show me what the actual instruction (pub fn closeacc(ctx: Context<CloseCounts ... etc) should look like?

Comment: The macro directive `#[account(mut, seeds = [COUNTSSEED], bump = countsbump, close = user)]` will already do everything, so the code for the actual instruction can be empty.

```
    pub fn close_counts(_ctx: Context<CloseCounts>, _countsbump: u8) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
```

Comment: Hi, when building I get the error:
the trait `ZeroCopy` is not implemented for `WorkerData`" 
WorkerData is my struct that replaces your Counts in this line:
pub counts_account: AccountLoader<'info, Counts>,

how can I implement this "zero loader" ?

Comment: If you don't use `zero_copy` for your PDA, just replace my `pub counts_account: AccountLoader<'info, Counts>,` with `pub counts_account: AccountInfo<'info, Counts>,`. Obviously also replace `Counts` with your own PDA name.